# Understanding some code from my homework

Tags: java

I'm learning java and I have an exercise when I need to find the number of shows for each number in an array, the numbers are 0-100, and this need to be done in O(n). Now I didn't know how to do this so I saw the solution and didn't really understand it, the explanation for the solution is very poor, here's the code:

```
public static void count (int [] data){
    final int N = 100;
    int [] temp = new int[N];
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < data.length; i++){
        temp[data[i]]+=1;  
    }
    for (i=0; i < N; i++){
        if ( temp[i] != 0)
            System.out.println(i + ":" +temp[i]);
    }

}
```

I specially didn't get the line

```
temp[data[i]]+=1;
```

If someone can explain me the idea of every line in the code,
I really appreciate any help. thanks!

Comment: What was the explanation? What didn't you understand from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, that code does this:
1) Initializes temp array with 100 positions (all set to 0);
2) Iterates over data array and increments the value relative to the index of the data array value it's processing. Take this example:

```java
int[] data = {23,11,10,23,5};

temp[data[0]] += 1
temp[23] += 1
temp[23] = temp[23] + 1 = 0 + 1 = 1

temp[data[1]] += 1
temp[11] += 1
temp[11] = temp[11] + 1 = 0 + 1 = 1

temp[data[2]] += 1
temp[10] += 1
temp[10] = temp[10] + 1 = 0 + 1 = 1

temp[data[3]] += 1
temp[23] += 1
temp[23] = temp[23] + 1 = 1 + 1 = 2

temp[data[4]] += 1
temp[5] += 1
temp[5] = temp[5] + 1 = 0 + 1 = 1
```

So in this case, you'll notice that value 23 occurs two times in the data array, while the other ones occur only one time. This way, you can count the occurrences in O(n), that is, with just one traversal of the array.

Comment: Make sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
/* method signature
static - method can be used without instantiation of the class
public - can be accessed by other classes
void - the return of the function count.
int [] data - parameter of the function. This function receives an array of int
*/

public static void count (int [] data){
    final int N = 100;
    int [] temp = new int[N];
    int i;

 //for i = 0 until i < size of the array passed as parameter, increment 1 in i

    for (i=0; i < data.length; i++){

/*
each iteration of this for increments 1 in the array temp at the position informed by the value of parameter data in position i.
caution: this can bring serious problems of segmentation fault, in other words, you can try to store in a position of the array temp that doesn't exist.
This will happen because you cannot guarantee the number that will be store in data[i]. If data[i] > 99 (because N = 100), you will face a segmentation fault.
*/

        temp[data[i]]+=1;  
    }

//here you will print the value stored at temp array in position i. From 0 to 99   

    for (i=0; i < N; i++)
    {
            if ( temp[i] != 0)
                System.out.println(i + ":" +temp[i]);
    }

}

HOPE IT HELPS.

You need to study more. Your question is so naive.
```